# cakephp and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, sql-calc-found-rows

I am trying to add the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS into a query (Please note this isn't for pagination)

please note I am trying to add this to a cakePHP query the code I currently have is below:

```
return $this->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => $conditions,
                'fields'=>array('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS','Category.*','COUNT(`Entity`.`id`) as `entity_count`'),
                'joins' => array('LEFT JOIN `entities` AS Entity ON `Entity`.`category_id` = `Category`.`id`'),
                'group' => '`Category`.`id`',
                'order' => $sort,
                'limit'=>$params['limit'],
                'offset'=>$params['start'],
                'contain' => array('Domain' => array('fields' => array('title')))
            ));
```

Note the `'fields'=>array('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS','` this obviously doesn't work as It tries to apply the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to the table e.g. `SELECT`Category`.`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`,`

Is there anyway of doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I know exactly how it do without cake, I am forced with a framework for this project, and the manual isn't very helpful this time... Always the manual first for me!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [cakephp paginate using mysql SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793231/cakephp-paginate-using-mysql-sql-calc-found-rows). The person had similar syntax as you have and it worked for him.

If that doesn't help you can always use `$this->find('count', $params);` (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1020/find-count) or `$this->query('YOUR SQL QUERY HERE');` (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1027/query).

Besides that you should not use `'joins'` together with `'contain'`. According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables) that "*could lead to some SQL errors (duplicate tables), so you need to use the joins method as an alternative for Containable*".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make your field parameter as below:

```
'fields'=>array('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *','COUNT(`Entity`.`id`) as `entity_count`')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to realize it with cake built in functions.

```
$dbo = $this->User->getDataSource();

//buildStatement() creates a Standard SQL Statement
$subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields' => $fields,
        'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this->User),
        'alias' => 'User',
        'limit' => null,
        'offset' => null,
        'joins' => array(),
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'order' => null,
        'group' => null
    ),
    $this->User
);

//Add the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS part
$subQuery = str_replace('SELECT', 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS', $subQuery);
$Users = $this->User->query($subQuery);

//Get FOUND ROWS
$foundRows = $this->User->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
$count = intval($foundRows[0][0]['FOUND_ROWS()']);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work as we are using the containable behavoir and there are multiple queries performed when calling the query() / find() functions

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible, **horrible** hack to get an unescaped `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` into the query, but it works:

```
$categories = $this->Category->find('all', array(
   'fields' => array('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 0.0 AS dummy_field,1', 'Category.*', ...),
   'limit'  => 42,
   ...
));
$totalCategories = $this->Category->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as `total_categories`');
```

All credit goes to "Kani" from http://mogura.in/blog/2011/06/17/cakephp-1-3-sql_calc_found_rows.